# SQL Foreign Key Constraint Error 1215

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

We are trying to make a simple database but we are always facing the same error and for the record I did check other foreign key constraint questions but they didn't helped at all.

As you know when we convert our EER diagram to Relations Map, relations take primary keys of the entities they are connected, in example:
Lets say our entites have one primary key each of them like TC_NO, randevu_no, hasta_no and our relationt hat tied them going to take primary keys of those entities.
Like;

```
CREATE TABLE REQUEST(
TC_NO int not null,
randevu_no int not null,
hasta_no int not null,
PRIMARY KEY(randevu_no,TC_NO,hasta_no),
FOREIGN KEY(hasta_no) REFERENCES PATIENT(hasta_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(randevu_no) REFERENCES APPOINTMENT(randevu_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(TC_NO) REFERENCES PATIENT(TC_NO) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

However, we are always getting the same error. There is no misspelling we checked this for hours but couldn't solved it and we have no idea why this is not working.

For the people that need all code of the database:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON(
    isim varchar(12) not null,
    soyisim varchar(12) not null,
    cinsiyet char(1) not null,
    dogum_tarihi date not null,
    adres varchar(150) not null,
    TC_NO int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(TC_NO),
    UNIQUE KEY(TC_NO));
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
    departman varchar(20) not null,
    sicil_no int not null,
    TC_NO int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(TC_NO,sicil_no),
    UNIQUE KEY(sicil_no),
    FOREIGN KEY(TC_NO) REFERENCES PERSON(TC_NO) ON DELETE CASCADE
    );
CREATE TABLE PATIENT(
    hastalik_gecmisi varchar(400) not null,
    kan_grubu char(4) not null,
    hasta_no int not null,
    TC_NO int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(TC_NO,hasta_no),
    FOREIGN KEY(TC_NO) REFERENCES PERSON(TC_NO) ON DELETE CASCADE
    );
CREATE TABLE DOCTOR(
    diploma_no int not null,
    brans varchar(40) not null,
    sicil_no int not null,
    TC_NO int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(TC_NO,sicil_no,diploma_no),
    FOREIGN KEY(TC_NO) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(TC_NO) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(sicil_no) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(sicil_no) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENT(
    hasta_no int not null,
    departman varchar(20) not null,
    randevu_no int not null,
    doktor_no int not null,
    tarih date not null,
    saat int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(randevu_no)
);
CREATE TABLE SECRETARY(
    TC_NO int not null,
    sicil_no int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(sicil_no,TC_NO),
    FOREIGN KEY(sicil_no) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(sicil_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(TC_NO) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(TC_NO) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE REQUEST(
    TC_NO int not null,
    randevu_no int not null,
    hasta_no int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(randevu_no,TC_NO,hasta_no),
    FOREIGN KEY(hasta_no) REFERENCES PATIENT(hasta_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(randevu_no) REFERENCES APPOINTMENT(randevu_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(TC_NO) REFERENCES PATIENT(TC_NO) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE NOTIFY(
    randevu_no int not null,
    sicil_no int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(randevu_no,sicil_no),
    FOREIGN KEY(randevu_no) REFERENCES APPOINTMENT(randevu_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(sicil_no) REFERENCES SECRETARY(sicil_no) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE CONFIRMATION(
    hasta_no int not null,
    sicil_no_s int not null,
    diploma_no int not null,
    sicil_no_d int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(sicil_no_s,hasta_no,diploma_no,sicil_no_d),
    FOREIGN KEY(sicil_no_s) REFERENCES SECRETARY(sicil_no_s) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(hasta_no) REFERENCES PATIENT(hasta_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(diploma_no) REFERENCES DOCTOR(diploma_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(sicil_no_d) REFERENCES DOCTOR(sicil_no_d) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just found the solution.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
This links make me thinking and with try-fail way I found the solution.

When you make a foreign key from a table and if that key also is a foreign key in that table you should do the foreign keys, also unique keys so they can have their indexes and connect with lower tables.

Answer (score 0):

does Patient table have a composite key as the primary key ? Can you show the create statements of the other tables too?

Comment: Nope it doesen't have a composotie key as the primary key and I added full code of database to main question.

Comment: I also faced the same problem last night.I tried it once again with your tables also but in vain.You can add one foreign key from patient table but not the other.. i think this is a limitation in mysql.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: I found and fixed the problem, writing as a new anwser.